# SQL Query won't return what is in the row (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, database, echo

My PHP:

```
<?php

function connectDB($user, $pass) {
    try {   
        return(new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Test;", $user, $pass));
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        return $ex;
    }
}


$db = connectDB("root", "root");
    if ($db instanceof PDOException) {
        die($db->getMessage());
    }
$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE`";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetch();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['VALUE1'];
    echo $row['VALUE2'];
    echo $row['VALUE3'];
}
?>
```

It only echo's the first letter of each value.

Here is what my table looks like:

```
VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
gomeow book   nothing
other  book   nothing
```

It only prints out the first letter of the first row many times
Prints out: ggggggbbbbbbnnnnnn

Comment: what about error_reporting? is it on ? error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything as I'm using PDO's. I did a row count and it turned up 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error logs, and try with this and let me know then -

```
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: I didn't think to check the error logs... I had the case wrong on 'Table'. I am still having an issue: it prints out ggggggbbbbbbnnnnnn. I am sure that that is not what is in the table. It appears to have printed the first letter of each value in the row.

Comment: @gomeow If it is returning anything, then why this => "SQL Query won't return anything (PHP)"

Comment: It was not returning anything, at all, when I posted this

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it by changing fetch() to fetchAll()

Comment: @gomeow good to hear you fixed it on your own :) cheers !!! Just a suggestion.. you may add you work as an answer for your future reference :)